# Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery in SSMS

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to run the following code in SQL Server Management Studio 2012:

```
SELECT
    ib.IFLOC AS Location,
    ib.IFITEM AS KitPart,
    im.ICDSC1 AS KitPart_Description,
    kd.ILCMPN AS ComponentPart,
    ib.IFPRVN AS Vendor,
    ib.IFSTK AS Stock,
    ib.IFLRD AS Last_Receipt_Date, 
    ib.IFLEAD AS Lead_Time,
    vn.ACBUYR AS Buyer,
    iv.IGMORD AS MOQ,
    SUM(ib.IFQOH) AS QOH,
    SUM(ib.IFQPO) AS QOO, 
    SUM(ib.IFQCM) AS QCM,
    SUM(ib.IFQBO) AS QBO,
    CAST(ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN sd.SBINDT > DateAdd(day, - 30, GetDate()) THEN sd.SBQSHP ELSE 0 END), 0) AS DECIMAL(8, 2)) AS Last_30_Days, 
    CAST(ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN sd.SBINDT BETWEEN DateAdd(day, - 60, GetDate()) AND DateAdd(day, - 31, GetDate()) THEN sd.SBQSHP ELSE 0 END), 0) AS DECIMAL(8, 2)) AS Thirty1_to_60_Days,
    CAST(ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN sd.SBINDT BETWEEN DateAdd(day, - 90, GetDate()) AND DateAdd(day, - 61, GetDate()) THEN sd.SBQSHP ELSE 0 END), 0) AS DECIMAL(8, 2)) AS Sixty1_to_90_Days, 
    CAST(ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN sd.SBINDT > DateAdd(day, - 90, GetDate()) THEN sd.SBQSHP ELSE 0 END), 0) AS DECIMAL(6, 2)) AS L90, 
    CAST(ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN sd.SBINDT BETWEEN DateAdd(day, - 120, GetDate()) AND DateAdd(day, - 91, GetDate()) THEN sd.SBQSHP ELSE 0 END), 0) AS DECIMAL(8, 2)) AS Ninety1_to_120_Days,
    CAST(ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN sd.SBINDT > DateAdd(day, - 365, GetDate()) THEN sd.SBQSHP ELSE 0 END), 0) AS DECIMAL(8, 2)) AS Last_12_Months,
    SUM(ib.IFQOH - ib.IFQCM) AS Available, 
    CAST(ROUND(SUM(CAST(ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN sd.SBINDT > DateAdd(day, - 90, GetDate()) THEN sd.SBQSHP ELSE 0 END), 0) AS DECIMAL(6, 2)) / 12), 2) AS NUMERIC(8, 2)) AS 'Three_Mo_wkly_Avg',
    CAST(ROUND(SUM(CAST(ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN sd.SBINDT > DateAdd(day, - 365, GetDate()) THEN sd.SBQSHP ELSE 0 END), 0) AS DECIMAL(8, 2)) / 52), 2) AS NUMERIC(8, 2)) AS 'L12Mo_wkly_Avg',
    CASE WHEN tm.Part IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS TopMover,
    CASE WHEN irl.Part IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS IRL,
    CASE WHEN csl.Part IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS CSL,
    CASE WHEN sgc.Part IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS SGC,
    SUM(CASE WHEN po.PBDUE < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) THEN po.PBDQTY ELSE 0 END) AS PastDue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN po.PACONF LIKE '%CONF%' AND po.PBDUE >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND po.PBDUE <> '2049-12-31' THEN po.PBDQTY ELSE 0 END) AS Confirmed, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN po.PACONF NOT LIKE '%CONF%' AND po.PBDUE >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) THEN po.PBDQTY WHEN po.PBDUE = '2049-12-31' THEN po.PBDQTY ELSE 0 END) AS Unconfirmed
FROM
    S2K_IB AS ib
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    S2K_IM AS im ON im.ICITEM = ib.IFITEM
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    SalesData sd ON sd.SBITEM = ib.IFITEM AND sd.DefaultLocation = ib.IFLOC AND sd.SBTYPE = 'O'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    TopMovers tm ON tm.Part = ib.IFITEM
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    IRL irl ON irl.Part = ib.IFITEM
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    SpringGapCloser sgc ON sgc.Part = ib.IFITEM
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    NewCSL csl ON csl.Part = ib.IFITEM
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    PurchaseOrders po ON po.PBITEM = ib.IFITEM AND po.PBLOC = ib.IFLOC AND po.PBTYPE NOT IN ('D', 'R') AND po.PASTAT <> 'X' AND po.PBUSER <> 'MDALTON'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    S2K_IV iv ON iv.IGITEM = ib.IFITEM AND iv.IGLOC = ib.IFLOC AND iv.IGVND = ib.IFPRVN
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    S2K_VEND vn ON vn.ACVEND = ib.IFPRVN
    INNER JOIN
    KitData kd ON kd.ILASSM = ib.IFITEM AND kd.ILLOC = ib.IFLOC
GROUP BY
    ib.IFLOC,
    ib.IFITEM,
    im.ICDSC1,
    kd.ILCMPN, 
    ib.IFPRVN,
    ib.IFSTK,
    ib.IFLRD, 
    ib.IFLEAD,
    vn.ACBUYR,
    iv.IGMORD,
    tm.Part,
    irl.Part,
    csl.Part,
    sgc.Part
ORDER BY
    KitPart,
    Location
```

I receive the following error on this line of code:

```
CAST(ROUND(SUM(CAST(ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN sd.SBINDT > DateAdd(day, - 90, GetDate()) THEN sd.SBQSHP ELSE 0 END), 0) AS DECIMAL(6, 2)) / 12), 2) AS NUMERIC(8, 2)) AS 'Three_Mo_wkly_Avg'
```

Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

How can this code be rewritten to work properly?

Comment: Cannot help you if you don't post the whole query

Comment: Have to break it up, it's sum of a sum that it's complaining about. Be worth doing anyway seeing as it's near unintelligible in it's current form.  Select X, Sum(y) From (Select X1, Sum(Z) From SomeWhereElse) dummyQuery  inner join anotherthing on anotherThing.X = dummyQuery.x1 Group by X is the sort of format you should be looking at.

Comment: I originally had it as two separate queries.  CAST(ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN sd.SBINDT > DateAdd(day, - 90, GetDate()) 
                                                                                                                                                                                 THEN sd.SBQSHP ELSE 0 END), 0) AS DECIMAL(6, 2)) AS L90 and then CAST(ROUND(SUM(b.L90 / 12), 2) 
                                                                                                                                                         AS NUMERIC(8, 2)) AS 'Three_Mo_wkly_Avg'

Comment: When you hand this over to maintenance, go for a full identity change, because if they find you it's not going to be pretty :) . If it were me, I'd be doing this in bits, when management come along and want it twiddled with, they are not going to like the estimate.

Comment: I am management and I am the only one that will "twiddle" with it.  I just made a subquery and handled it that way.

Comment: Try putting those two sd columns in the group by

Comment: That did not work Blam.